# "Sophisticated" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have look up in many web dictionaries but can't find which definition of "sophisticated" appropriate in this context.

> Angela : Forget it, Joey. I'm with Bob now.
>
> Joey : Bob? Who the hell's Bob?
>
> Angla : Bob is great. He's smart, he's **sophisticated**, and he has a
>   real job.

(Friends SS1.ep5 05:24).

Hope someone could explain to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word sophisticated comes from an Ancient Greek word, Sofist, which was a teacher of philosophy, math, music and many other things. Sophisticated means that a person is knowledgeable about many different subjects. It is often used to mean that the person is well educated, has good manners or is interesting to talk to.